# PDOException error PHP SQL "Firstname Cannot be Null"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I currently have a problem with the code I have below..

It keeps saying

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Firstname' cannot be null' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\checkregister.php:30 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\checkregister.php(30): PDOStatement->execute() 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\checkregister.php on line 30
```

I've tried everything I know but I just cannot remove that error... any kind of help is really appreciated :D
This php file is called checkregister.php

```
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
  #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
  $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO members 
           (firstname, surname, DD, MM, YYYY, 
           email, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5)
          VALUES 
           (:firstname, :surname, :DD, :MM, :YYYY, 
           :email, :Player1, :Player2, :Player3, :Player4, :Player5)');

  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_GET['firstname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $_GET['surname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':DD', $_GET['DD']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':MM', $_GET['MM']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':YYYY', $_GET['YYYY']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_GET['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':Player1', $_GET['Player1']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':Player2', $_GET['Player2']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':Player3', $_GET['Player3']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':Player4', $_GET['Player4']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':Player5', $_GET['Player5']);
  $stmt->execute();
```

This is my form in another php file:

```
<form name="register" method="post" action="checkregister.php">

<!--Text, using <p> tag for new line-->
Main Account Registration <p>
* All Fields Mandatory <P>


<div class="required_field">
<label for="leadername">Team Leader's First Name</label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" value="hihi"><p>
<span id="firstnameerror" class="error"></span>
</div>

the same code repeats for each of the other ones such as Surname, DD MM YY, etc

<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Register">
<input type="reset" name="resetbutton" id="resetbutton" value="Clear all Fields">
</form>
```

Comment: what is your query string in the url?

Comment: If this helps.. I'm using dreamweaver to make the codes and im using XAMPP (PHPmyadmin, MySQL, APACHE)

Comment: Your code will not work unless you query string contains a `key=value` pair for each of the parameters.

Comment: If you mean just the url.. http://localhost/clubresults/checkregister.php  (this is the php file containing only those codes shown above) the forms are in another php file

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
Sorry but i'm not quite sure what you mean.. could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I've made an edit to the question which might help you understand my issue better :P Many Thanks to everyone replies to the question

Comment: Either change method to `GET` in the form or change `$_GET` to `$_POST` in the php code.

Comment: oooh yes! it worked! you are such a legend d_inevitable! thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working backwards:

- MySQL complains about a null value; so why is null received?
- PDO passes null to MySQL if a null value is passed in `bindParam()`; why are we passing a null value?
- When a variable in PHP is not defined and you attempt to use it, it will a) issue a warning and b) implicitly set it to null; why are we using an undefined variable?
- The `$_GET['firstname']` is not defined (amongst others); why is is not defined?
- You're using `method="post"` in your form, so the form entries are passed via `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

It happen due to data mismatching i was facing same problem while runnig a cronjob to update products in magento some of the products was deleted and the scripts was running from a table in database where entry of deleted products was pending and while updating the products using products id its giving the error **PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:**

I set condition to check the products exist or not and it work fine for me.